Why does terra produce different value ranges for the same raster?
I have been using terra to read and then save various global raster data sets. Today I noticed quite different value ranges depending on how I look at the data or what I do with it. I am confused and nervous to undertake any analyses until I can explain why I am seeing what I am seeing. I would be most grateful if any among you could let me know why the value ranges I am seeing are so different.
Using global road density as an example. I import the GRIP Total density, all types combined ascii raster using terra as follows:
roadDir <- c("downloads/GRIP4_density_total/")

tmp <- paste0(roadDir, "grip4_total_dens_m_km2.asc")

roadDensity <- terra::rast(tmp)


If I then look at roadDensity I see that the range of values is 0 to 99445 (m per square km):
> roadDensity
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 2160, 4320, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 0.08333333, 0.08333333  (x, y)
extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 
source      : grip4_total_dens_m_km2.asc 
name        : grip4_total_dens_m_km2 
min value   :                      0 
max value   :                  99445 

If I import the original data into QGIS I get the same cell size, dimensions and value range as shown in the code snippet above so I take those values as the true values in the data. So far so good.
Problems emerge when: a) I look at summaries of the data or b) write the resulting raster to a .tif file for use in further processing.
a) Summary
terra::global(roadDensity, c( "min", "max"), na.rm=TRUE)
                       min    max
grip4_total_dens_m_km2   0 330306


I do not understand why I am now getting a very different max value (330306).
b) Write to .tif
x <- writeRaster(roadDensity,"test.tif", datatype="INT4U", overwrite=TRUE)

x
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 2160, 4320, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 0.08333333, 0.08333333  (x, y)
extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
source      : test.tif 
name        : grip4_total_dens_m_km2 
min value   :                      0 
max value   :                 330306 


So terra's global and writeRaster produce the same results.
I understand that through changing the datatype value to one of its possibilities ("INT1U", "INT2U", "INT4U") writeRaster changes the value range because of the max possible values that particular data structure can hold. What I do not understand is how "INT4U" can increase the value range so dramatically beyond the original without any change in cell size. In addition the INT*U value should not change the summary values produced by global.
I am sure its a very simple thing and I am due an "ah duh" moment, but I would appreciate any guidance to aid my understanding and thence analytical confidence.
Thank you

some summary functions in R only look at a random sample of the data to create summary statistics, if the data exceeds a certrain size. looke here

When I run roadDensity <- rast("grip4_total_dens_m_km2.asc"), then global(roadDensity, c( "min", "max"), na.rm=TRUE), the min == 0 and the max == 330306. Check your R environment for a stray SpatRaster, or start a fresh R session and try again.

To elaborate further, after running roadDensity <- rast("grip4_total_dens_m_km2.asc"), then roadDensity, there are no default min/max values showing. I have to run roadDensity[] <- values(roadDensity) to get them to show in the metadata. Again, min ==0, max == 330306. So yeah, try starting the process again from the beginning.

What code are you using to " look at roadDensity"?

Thanks D.J. I am aware of the sampling but am under the impression that global uses all the data unless you use the weight function. Happy to be corrected.

Thanks L Tyrone. Started fresh R session and same result. On my system (ubuntu 22.04) I just have to "run" the roadDensity object to see the results I presented.

What happens if you run roadDensity[] <- values(roadDensity) then roadDensity? The only other thing I can suggest, if an answer is not forthcoming here, is to raise an issue on GitHub.

@L Tyrone "What happens if you run roadDensity[] <- values(roadDensity) then roadDensity?" Got the same result. Thanks for trying.

I do not see that. My best guess is that QGIS has created a sidecar file with approximate extreme values.
Get the data in a clean folder
dir.create("test")
setwd("test")
url <- "https://dataportaal.pbl.nl/downloads/GRIP4/GRIP4_density_total.zip"
zip <- basename(url)
if (!file.exists(zip)) {
   download.file(url, zip, mode="wb")
   unzip(zip)
}

min and max are not reported for an ascii file (as these are not stored in the file format)
library(terra)
#terra 1.7.78

r <- rast("grip4_total_dens_m_km2.asc")
r
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 2160, 4320, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 0.08333333, 0.08333333  (x, y)
#extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (CRS84) (OGC:CRS84) 
#source      : grip4_total_dens_m_km2.asc 
#name        : grip4_total_dens_m_km2 

Make a new SpatRaster to reveal the min and max values:
r * 1
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 2160, 4320, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 0.08333333, 0.08333333  (x, y)
#extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (CRS84) (OGC:CRS84) 
#source(s)   : memory
#varname     : grip4_total_dens_m_km2 
#name        : grip4_total_dens_m_km2 
#min value   :                      0 
#max value   :                 330306 

Or compute them like this:
minmax(r, compute=TRUE)
#    grip4_total_dens_m_km2
#min                      0
#max                 330306

Perhaps you can try this again in an empty folder. I am guessing that in your folder there is a sidecar file left from previous work (e.g. grip4_total_dens_m_km2.xml) that provides these numbers. Perhaps this file was created by QGIS, possibly using a quick estimate. Also please report the version of terra you are using.

Thank you for a most awesome package @RobertHijmans. I did as you suggest and got the same results you displayed. I was using terra 1.7.78. Apologies for taking up your time but appreciate your response. I am not 100% sure what caused the problem but think it may be due to saving the rasters as .rda files and then reloading into the global environment for use. I consistently got this error which probably caused the issue:
Error in .External(list(name = "CppMethod__invoke_notvoid", address = <pointer: (nil)>,  :
NULL value passed as symbol address
Thank you for your help!

You can save a SpatRaster with writeRDS but I do not recommend it (use .tif instead). You cannot use save  (that is probably what you mean with ".rda"); the objects will be corrupted when you load them again, But this is not related to the issue you were reporting.

It is somewhat related to the original question: I came upon the problem when trying to package various spatial data sets for a data package that I could then load and use in modelling. The recommendation (https://r-pkgs.org/data.html) is to save data files as .rda (what save produces). I discovered through trial and error and the suggestions you made that saving rasters as anything other than .tif is problematic. That makes packaging them that much harder and accessing them using the package very clunky. It hardly seems worth the packaging effort. Thanks for your help and superb packages.

You can store data in any format with a package and it is trivial to write a function that returns it in a desired form. E.g: elev_data <- \() terra::rast(system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra")).

Thanks Robert. I will give that a shot. Best regards.
